# Segmentation fault, Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, segmentation-fault, sidekiq

I am getting this error on my Sidekiq process:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:318: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0053 p:---- s:0210 b:0210 l:000209 d:000209 CFUNC  :syswrite
c:0052 p:0181 s:0206 b:0206 l:000205 d:000205 METHOD /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:318
c:0051 p:0013 s:0197 b:0197 l:000196 d:000196 METHOD /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:336
c:0050 p:0021 s:0193 b:0193 l:000192 d:000192 METHOD /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:201
c:0049 p:0018 s:0188 b:0188 l:000180 d:000187 BLOCK  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/grocer-0.4.1/lib/grocer/connection.rb:24
c:0048 p:0025 s:0186 b:0186 l:000185 d:000185 METHOD /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/grocer-0.4.1/lib/grocer/connection.rb:56
c:0047 p:0011 s:0181 b:0181 l:000180 d:000180 METHOD /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/grocer-0.4.1/lib/grocer/connection.rb:23
c:0046 p:0043 s:0177 b:0177 l:000176 d:000176 METHOD /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/delegate.rb:72
```

the full trace is [here](http://pastebin.com/qJpy7Gs5)

I have no idea how to go about it. It seems to be coming from OpenSSL. Can someone point out how do I even begin to debug this? Thanks

P.S. I am uploading the error on pastebin because it exceeds character limit of SO.

Comment: Can you give more information about your system version, OpenSSL version, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I found that they had a [similar error doing IMAP](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/43822), and the problem was that they were using a readonly connection when they should have been using a read-write one. Check your Grocer configuration and permissions, you may be having the same problem.